# Does os.exec from go (golang) not execute commands in $PATH?

Tags: macos, go

I was trying to execute shell commands using the exec library for go (golang). However, I whenever I tried to execute it using binaries that I installed with `go install` it didn't work.

I tried running my binaries just on the terminal and they work. I checked that my $PATH did have the bin file for my go path so thats good in the terminal. But then I tried to do that same check in os exec by doing:

```
echo := exec.Command("echo", "$PATH")
b, err := echo.Output()
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
fmt.Println(string(b))
```

But suprisingly, it works in a weird way, it echos the literal string `$PATH`!! Incredible! Is there something that I am doing wrong? I can't even see what $PATH os exec is actually running...nor can I run my binaries in go exec as commands as in:

`exec.Command("myCommand").Run()`

Anyone has any suggestions as to why this might be?

The issue with this question is **not printing** `$PATH`. What isn't working is that I can't run commands installed under `$GOPATH/bin` even though its under `$PATH`

Comment: so, what *does* `os.Getenv("PATH")` show? Does the go process have the environment you think it does?

Comment: @JimB great idea! Unfortunately, it does have my $GOPATH at the end, as expected! :(

Comment: @JimB So I figured it out. It was running the command, but because the command I made was returning an error, so was exec and I couldn't tell if it was exiting because it wasn't finding the command or because my command was buggy. Apologize everyone, though I did learn how to look at environment variables and that exec doesn't literrally execute what you send it...because if it did, it should execute echo $PATH with the path, not the literal string $PATH

Answer (score 6):

You're trying to run a shell command, `echo $PATH` without using a shell to do the variable expansion. The `echo` being run is a binary, probably /bin/echo, and it is being passed the string `$PATH`. $PATH doesn't expand since that's a function of the shell and it's not involved so no expansion occurs.  To get what you expected you need to use the shell to run the command, e.g. `exec.Command("sh", "-c",  "echo $PATH")`

Comment: sure but that wasn't the main issue of my question. Thnks anyway.

Answer (score 5):

Environment variable expansion is a shell feature, not a program feature.

You will have to use `os.Getenv("PATH")`.

```
echo := exec.Command("echo", os.Getenv("PATH"))
```

<strike>Or you could use [`os.ExpandEnv`](http://golang.org/pkg/os/#ExpandEnv):</strike>

```
echo := exec.Command(strings.Fields(os.ExpandEnv("echo $PATH"))...)
```

Comment: I am more interested in running the commands I `go installed` not printing `$PATH`. Why would `echo := exec.Command(strings.Fields(os.ExpandEnv("echo $PATH"))...)` run the command I go installed as in `exec.Command("myCommand").Run()`?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean? did you read the documentation for ExpandEnv?

Comment: Yes I did. The main issue with my question is that even though $PATH in my shell has the correct stuff, it still does not run commands under $GOPATH/bin$. I guess with you suggestion I could just run it by doing `exec.Command((os.ExpandEnv("echo $PATH"))+"myCommand")`, in fact I am going to try it right now. Though, its kind of an odd way of doing it (i.e. its odd it doesn't let me do it directly as in `exec.Command("myCommand").Run()`)

Comment: Oohhh I misunderstood your question, actually `exec.Command("myCommand").Run()` should work as long as `$PATH` includes `$GOPATH/bin`, did you run `go install` on your `mycommand`?

Comment: Please read the docs for [Cmd](http://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#Cmd) where you'll see that a path (to the command you're trying to run) is required.

Comment: @OneOfOne I apologize, you are right, I wrote my quesiton weirdly. I will try to re-write it. Dmitri I will read it now.

Comment: @DmitriGoldring: you don't need a path for `exec.Command`, it uses LookPath to build the `Cmd`

Comment: @DmitriGoldring I am a little skeptical about that the command needs to be given a path, then how is it running other commands I have sent it like `echo` and `redis-server` or `redis-cli`. Shouldn't I be specifying the full path?

Comment: True @JimB. I run my apps on a server as a user with minimal environment so I always provide a path. It's less painful than eventually realizing you're running the wrong binary :)

Comment: So I figured it out. It was running the command, but because the command I made was returning an error, so was exec and I couldn't tell if it was exiting because it wasn't finding the command or because my command was buggy. Apologize everyone, though I did learn how to look at environment variables and that exec doesn't literrally execute what you send it...because if it did, it should execute `echo $PATH` with the path, not the literal string $PATH.

Answer (score 1):

So I figured it out why I wasn't able to run my command. This was my original code:

```
cmd := exec.Command("my command")
b, err := cmd.Output()
//fmt.Println("string(b):", string(b)) //<--inspecting stdout before throwing an error revealed that it *was* doing my command!
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
fmt.Println("string(b):", string(b)) //<-- wouldn't run so I would never see its out put.
```

It was running the command, but because the command I made was returning an error, so was exec and I couldn't tell if it was exiting because it wasn't finding the command or because my command was buggy. So if the command throws an error but also writes to stdout, you can have "valid" information on both of `.Output()'s` return value.

The only reason I was trying to print `$PATH` was to see if my command was even in $PATH for go's exec env. But was OneOfOne's answer clearly states, it can be found by:

```
echo := exec.Command("echo", os.Getenv("PATH"))
```